# jquery random video background not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "/08/anek-ferry-traghetti-grecia.mp4";
image[1] = "/12/Composizione-2.mp4";
image[2] = "/11/Composizione-1.mp4";
var hasard = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length);

$('#fond-aleatoire video').attr('src', 'http://neos.anekitalia.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018' + image[hasard]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id class="fond-aleatoire">
  <mediaelementwrapper id="mejs_8947924178991862">
    <video loop="loop" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" width="1920" 
    height="600" src="http://neos.anekitalia.com/wp- 
    content/uploads/2018/11/Composizione-1.mp4" 
    id="mejs_8947924178991862_html5" 
    preload="none" style="margin: 0px; width: 1903px; height: 594.688px;">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://neos.anekitalia.com/wp- 
              content/uploads/2018/11/Composizione-1.mp4">              
    </video>
  </mediaelementwrapper>
</div>
```

I have the following code that is working on all browsers but not in safari

this is simply changing randomly the default video background of my wordpress site when the background has ID #fond-aleatoire, any suggestion how to fix this on safari? many thanks.

Comment: please add the html

Comment: yes you are right I have just added to the post

Comment: are you getting any console messages in Safari?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have an available mac environment, I discovered the issue on a mac book of my colleague